# How can I pass a string comprised of an ASCII character repeated 'n' times as a command line argument to a simple c program?

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, terminal, command-line-arguments, buffer-overflow

I am learning about buffer overflow exploits. As is customary for beginners, I am working from a very simple 'C' program that uses an unsafe, non-validating function, such as gets(), to fill a fixed length declared buffer with a string command line argument stored in argv[]. For context, the program follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char buffer[512];
    if (argc < 2)
    {
        printf("Please feed the buffer :D");
        exit(0);
    }
    strcpy(buffer, argv[1]);
    printf("delicious input:  %s, buffer);
    return 0;
}
```

As you can see, manually typing an argument that would overflow this buffer is a nuisance, so I want to automate the process using built-in command line functionality. In particular, I want to craft a string that consists of an ASCII character repeated 'n' times and pass that as an argument to the program. Unfortunately, I am fairly illiterate with Linux command line (I am working on it). I read of this solution:

```
user@virtualenv:~$ printf 'somestring%.0s' {1..520}
```

However, the resulting string is not stored in argv[1] (printf is). In Python this would be as simple as:

```
'somestring'*2
```

Is it possible, using built-in functionality of the Linux terminal, to issues commands that would craft a string? How could this be done so that those commands are not passed as command line arguments -- only the resulting string product is stored in argv[]?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. I read about the function of the back-tick in Linux "`". Commands appearing between backticks will be evaluated down into a final, singular data type, which can passed along as an argument to a program.

In my case, I want to pass the resultant of the following bash command to the above program:

```
printf 'A%.0s' {1..520}
```

It will look like this:

```
user@virtualenv$ ./vuln.c `printf 'A%.0s' {1..520}`
```

The result is that a string of 520 A repeated consecutively will be passed to argv[1], causing the 512 character buffer to overflow.

Comment: You can use `$(...)` instead of `...` in bash. It also allows for nested command substitutions.

Comment: @Robert 's comment has an unfortunate formatting error; he is trying to say `$(printf ...)` is better than (backtick) `printf ...` (backtick)